# Does the JavaCC (.jj) format support comments?

Tags: java, comments, javacc

Can comments be added to a JavaCC (.jj) specification file?  What style should they be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the JavaCC format [supports Java-style comments](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hosking/javacc/doc/javaccgrm.html).  E.g.,

> White space in the grammar files also follows the same conventions as for the Java programming language. This includes the syntax for comments. Most comments present in the grammar files are generated into the generated parser/lexical analyzer.